# custom html module does not recognise code joomla

Tags: html, joomla, content-management-system

I am using the zo2 framework and trying to implement the accordion.
I copy the shortcode from the zo2 website which says

```
[ accordion ] [ acc_item title=title ]content[ /acc_item ] [ acc_item title=title ]content[ /acc_item ] [ /accordion ]
```

In my text editor, it displays in the slider position on the web home page.
When I check the homepage it always just shows the text namely
[ accordion ] [ acc_item title=title ]content[ /acc_item ] [ acc_item title=title ]content[ /acc_item ] [ /accordion ]

and does not recognise this as actual code and does not display the accordion.

Comment: make sure the plugin is enabled , also the copy paste may contain some spaces or html chars so type the code in the editor. The third party extension question should ask on their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the plugin that will transform that code to something meaningful is run before the "Content - Load Module" plugin. You should change its ordering to make it run after. Otherwise, it won't be able to read it.